# Regular expression to parse list of Python instructions between commas

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am writing a parser and, at some point, I am expecting a list of Python instructions and/or values written between commas. For example,

```
n >= 5, n < 20, m == len([1, 2, 3]), m + 1 == func(myObject.myMethod());
```

This is just an example, in practice I would like to be able to parse any valid Python expression.

My grammar has a rule of the form:

```
EXPRESSION ("," EXPRESSION)* ";"
```

where `EXPRESSION` is a regular expression that can accept any Python instruction. Of couse, since the comma could appear as part of my expression, I don't know how I could use it as a separator. Still, seems to me like there must be a regular expression, since any human can clearly parse the four expressions in the example above. Any ideas?

My current regex is `EXPRESSION = [^,;]+` but this of course only works for very simple cases; the example above cannot be parsed with this.

Comment: have you tried to create any regular expression for the given problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, as a comma in a Python instruction may be misinterpreted as a separator, but still yield valid Python instructions.

Here is an example:

```
a = 1, b = ((2, 3), 4), a, b = b, a, b = a
```

This can be interpreted as:

```
a = 1
b = ((2, 3), 4), a
b = b, a
b = a
```

Or as:

```
a = 1
b = ((2, 3), 4)
a, b = b
a, b = a
```

Or as:

```
a = 1
b = ((2, 3), 4)
a, b = b, a
b = a
```

All are valid pieces of code. There is no way you can know which is the intended one.

Comment: I see, thanks! Then the only way to achieve what I want is to use as separator a symbol never used by Python, right? I was considering this but it really made my language a lot less readable.

Comment: You could use JSON maybe? Then you would have `["a = 1", "b = ((2, 3), 4)", "a, b = b, a", "b = a"]`. Double quotes would be escaped with a backslash, ...etc, all defined by the JSON syntax. See [JSON encoder and decoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)